# My Java Class does not connect to MySQL running under WAMP

Tags: java, mysql, wamp

I tried all day to connect my database and added the jar file, and verified that everything is fine, unfortunately my teacher could not solve me since he works with an older version of netbeans
I leave my connection code, it should be noted that my port is 3308 and I am using the mariadb server

```java
    Connection con; 
    public conexion() { 
        try{
             Class.forName("org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver"); con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3308/prueba","root","") System.out.println("Conection finally"); 
        }
        catch(Exception e){ 
            System.out.println("conection error("); }
        } 
    public java.sql.Connection getConnection() {
        return null;
    }
```

I hope someone could help me, I would appreciate it very much :)
I tried to connect it directly from the command prompt and tried to find out how to do it but I didn't understand how in the end, I just want to know why it doesn't make the connection if I followed everything step by step and tried to understand the logic but I just don't understand what's happening
I also downloaded the jar file in my project

Comment: what is the output of `System.err.print(e.getMessage())` (inside your catch block)